# how can we install composer require spatie/laravel-searchable in 5.7 version of laravel

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout, laravel-searchable

I am setting up search in my project.which includes more than one model to search.Firstly, I tried using scout and scout extended but it does not give much flexibility with where clause.so I thought to have a look to `composer require spatie/laravel-searchable` but it seems its dependency is `laravel 5.8`.
but my `laravel` version is `5.7.28`.Please provide me the solution.

How should I proceed with the same?

I tried using scout and scout extended but it does not give much flexibility with where clause

```
  $channels = Channel::where('created_at', '>', now()->subDays(7))->get();
       return view('search.index')->with(compact('channels'));
```

this works perfectly as this is simple query but if I try the same with 
  the scout and algolia(search request)

```
$channels = Channel::search($request->q)->where('created_at', '>', now()- 
          >subDays(7))->get();
```

it does not give any result.

when I tried installing `composer require spatie/laravel-searchable`

I got this error

> Problem 1
>
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.7.28, 5.8.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev, v5.7.28].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev, v5.7.28].
> - spatie/laravel-searchable 1.3.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.8.0 -> 
>     satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev].
> - Installation request for spatie/laravel-searchable ^1.3 -> satisfiable 
>     by spatie/laravel-searchable[1.3.0].
> - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.7.28, required 
>     as 5.7.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.7 support droped with `v1.3.0` so you need to install the older version.

Changelog: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-searchable/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

You can install the older version using command:

`composer require spatie/laravel-searchable:1.2.3`

Or add this version into your `composer.json` file and run `composer update`

Comment: @anonymous let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you please help me if could resolve using scout and algolia. as I mentioned the query in question.

Comment: Still having issue with it?

Comment: no, spatie/searchable is installed but I had already implemented it using scout.I was using spatie as an alternative.So If I could get better answer for scout then I would not need to move to spatie.